# Subscribing to a feed for multiple tags

Tags: support, tags, feed, subscription, atom

I'd like to monitor the questions tagged with several tags, say [t1](/questions/tagged/t1) and [t2](/questions/tagged/t2). How can I get a single feed containing questions tagged with either [t1](/questions/tagged/t1) or [t2](/questions/tagged/t2) without any duplicates?

Comment: I think that the real question would be how to have a feed with all new questions with favorite tags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/t1+or+t2

Comment: .. and, as it turns out, currently you can get no more than 20 tags concatenated this way