# Can I subscribe to a combination of tags?

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching

Is there a way to subscribe to a combination of tags. For example I search for `[jquery][deferred]` so is there a way I can search for posts with **both** of these tags? The article linked in [this seemingly relevant question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23935/subscribing-to-a-feed-for-multiple-tags) is dead.

Comment: It's not a 'linked article' - it's an example of feed link. In your case it is http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/jquery+or+deferred

Comment: Subscribe or search? Those are totally different things.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd subscibe

Comment: @Artemix oops. thanks for pointing that out. sorry.

Comment: So why the misleading example? It led to irrelevant answer..

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd "Seemingly relevant". I was confused. `"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deferred+jquery"` is what I want. I will bookmark that.

Comment: @thomas - What you want is search not subscribe.

Comment: @hims056 I think I got what he want: subscribe to the search results..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably Filtered Questions. Create your own new filter by following [this link](https://stackexchange.com/filters/new).

1. Choose tag and site and save.
2. Edit the filter to add new rule with the second tag and save changes.
3. You can have it send email notifications to email of your choice.

I just created a [sample filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/91048/my-test-filter) for the two tags you mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an example given on that [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23936/186599)

You can search https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/jquery+or+deferred

and whatever tag you want you can replace them in the above link.