# What's the URL for the tag intersection feed for tags with +'s?

Tags: support, tags, subscription

I've just read this:

[Subscribing to a feed for multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23935/196834)

and learned that I can subscribe to

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/tag1+and+tag2

but what if `tag1` ends with `+`? e.g. `c++`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Url encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to the rescue!

`c++` on the url encodes as `c%2B%2B`.

Meaning you can use:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/tag1+and+c%2B%2B

Though, that does fail due to the ambiguity on the server side with understanding what `+` and what `%2B` decoded to `+` are.

So - use the tag synonym of `c++` instead - `cpp`:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/tag1+and+cpp

(where `%20` encodes a space).